# Python - Xpath with module requests_html to get value of "a href"

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have three problems, that are kind of related:

In the page https://www.maison-objet.com/paris/les-exposants, I would like to access the attribute "a href" of "BRITOP LIGHTING POLAND"

So this is what I wrote

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://www.maison-objet.com/paris/les-exposants'

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get(url)

r.html.render(sleep=1)

products = r.html.xpath('//*[@class="descBloc"]/h3/a').__getattribute__("href")

print(products)
```

I get this error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'href'

Second thing I notice: if I try to copy the XPath of "BRITOP LIGHTING POLAND", I get

> //*[@id="resultatsFiltres"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/h3/a

I don't understand why it is different

Third thing that doesn't work and I don't understand is:

```
products = r.html.find('.descBloc')[1]
        print(products)
```

But I get

> "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: to avoid an X-Y Problem: what are you trying to achieve? What information are you ultimately after, and in what format?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire I'm trying to retrieve the URL in order to click on each brand then closing some windows and log in and finally get the email in JSON format

Comment: `xpath()` always gives list (even if there is single element) and you have to use `[0]` to work with first element on list or use `for`-loop to work with all elements on list. You may similar problem with `find()[1]` - first element is `[0]`, not `[1]`

Comment: did you copy xpath from browser? Often the same element you can find using different xpath and browser doesn't have to create the same xpath as you. Browser often create long unreadable xpath but human is sparted and it can create shorted xpath.

Comment: there can be other problem - server may have complex system to detect bots/scripts and it may send different HTML then you expect - it may send Captcha.

Answer (score 1):

For issue #1, can you do one thing? Seems like it returns a list:

```py
products = r.html.xpath('//*[@class="descBloc"]/h3/a').__getattribute__("href")
for item in products:
    print(items)
```

For issue #2, can you check the `type`?

```py
type(r.html.find('.descBloc'))
```

if it is a `str` then you cannot use indexing.

Comment: This is what I get for issue #1: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'href' and for issue #2: <class 'list'>

Comment: @GrowyTobe I think #2 it's only return 1 item in the list. `r.html.find('.descBloc')[0]` should be return value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `request_html` has problem to load this page - maybe server detects bot/script and it sends different content, or it uses JavaScript which can't be executed by `request_html`

The only working code for me is with [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) which controls real web browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager


url = 'https://www.maison-objet.com/en/paris/les-exposants'

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

driver.get(url)

all_items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="descBloc"]/h3/a')
print('len(all_items):', len(all_items))

for item in all_items:
    print('text:', item.text)
    print('url :', item.get_attribute('href'))
    print('---')
```

Result:

```
len(all_items): 51
text: BRITOP LIGHTING POLAND
url : https://www.maison-objet.com/paris/les-exposants/britop-lighting-poland-today
---
text: FEELGOOD DESIGNS
url : https://www.maison-objet.com/paris/les-exposants/feelgood-designs-today
---
text: KASZER
url : https://www.maison-objet.com/paris/les-exposants/kaszer-fashion-accessories
---
text: 
url : https://www.maison-objet.com/paris/les-exposants/balma-capoduri-c-s-p-a-smart-gift
---
text: 
url : https://www.maison-objet.com/paris/les-exposants/goodwill-m-g-home-accessories
---
# ...
```

But result shows other problem - it gets `text` only for visible elements. Page may use `lazy-loading` and add elements when user scroll page (and when elements are visible in window). It may need some JavaScript code to scroll elements (`driver.execute_script(...)`)

---

**EDIT:**

I had to add `/en/` in url to get page in English instead of French.